# A barrel contains 10l of whiskey, another one contains 10l of coca-cola. If I do the following operation

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

A barrel contains 10l of whiskey, another one contains 10l of coca-cola. If I do the following operation in two steps:

1 step) with a glass I transfer 200ml of whiskey from the first barrel to the second one, and I mix the barrel very well.

2 step) After that, with a glass I transfer 200ml of the whiskey/coca-cola mix from the second barrel to the first one, and I mix very well. This way, now the two barrels contain again exactly 10l of liquid each.

If I repeat these two steps ten times, at the end will I have more coca-cola in the whiskey barrel or more whiskey in the coca-cola barrel?

Answer (score 3):

Never mind any of the transfer operations: the amount of whiskey in the cola barrel will be

> missing from the whiskey barrel.

This is enough to tell us that whenever there's an equal amount of liquid in both barrels, the amount of whiskey in the cola barrel will be

> exactly equal to the amount of cola that was needed to replace it in the whiskey barrel.